# Reducing primes in $\mathbb Z[i]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $4k+1=p$ be a prime.

Assume you do not know $p=a^2+b^2$(this is what we intend to prove).

Over $\mathbb Z[i]$, how does one prove that $p$ splits into conjugates?

That is, if $p = (a+bi)(c+di)$, then $a+bi=c-di$?

We know that $a-bi=t(c+di)$ where $t\in \mathbb R$, could give: $p=t(a^2+b^2)$. It could be that $t=p/m^2$ where $m^2=a^2+b^2$. How do you show $t=\pm 1$?

Does this work?

$a-bi=t(c+di)\implies (a-bi)(a+bi)=t(c+di)t(c-di)\implies(a^2+b^2)=t^2(c^2+d^2)\implies t^2=1(\mbox{since }a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=p)\implies t=\pm 1.$

Comment: As $p$ is real, everything nonzero, you get $c+di = t(a-bi)$ in integers. Since $p$ is prime, $t=1.$ I do not see how one proves that $p$ is no longer prime in $\mathbb Z[i]$ without constructing $p = u^2 + v^2$

Comment: @WillJagy ah brilliant $p=(a+bi)(c+di)=(a+bi)t(a-bi)=t(a^2+b^2)$. So is this a one line proof of sum of two squares theorem?

Comment: J.A., no, it is a one line proof that IF you already believe that $p$ is not prime in the Gaussian integers, the factorization takes a certain form (up to units).

Comment: thank you. I know that from $-1 \mod p \equiv x^2$, has a solution, $p$ is not a Gaussian prime. I am stuck at if $p = (a+bi)(c+di)$, then $a+bi=c-di$. Looking back, I miss a subtlety: If as you say $(a-bi)t=(c+di)$, then $t$ could be any real. Correct? then $p/t = a^2 +b^2$ could hold. So t can be some rational number right? For instance $a=7,b=24$, $t=p/25^2$.

Comment: " the factorization takes a certain form (up to units)" this is what I am missing.

Comment: The imaginary part of $(a+bi)(c+di)$ is $ad+bc.$ We require this to be zero. This means there is rational $t = x/y$ with $\gcd(x,y) = 1$ and $x(a,b) = y (c,-d).$ And on and on; for example, what is $\gcd(a,b)?$

Comment: I am inclined to say $gcd(a,b)=1$ but unsure.

Comment: If some integer $g$ divides both $a$ and $b,$ what happens to the factorization of $a^2 + b^2?$

Comment: thats right it becomes composite.

Comment: @WillJagy I have added an answer to the question based on your feedback. Could you check if it makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

The ring $\mathbf{Z} / p \mathbf{Z}$ is a field with $p-1$ nonzero elements. Since $4 | p-1$, there is a multiplicative subgroup of order $4$.

A field can only have two square roots of unity, therefore $\mathbf{Z} / p \mathbf{Z}$ already has a fourth root of unity $m$.

Pick your favorite reason why this implies $p\mathbf{Z}[i]$ cannot be a prime ideal of $\mathbf{Z}[i]$: e.g. some simple things things you can use are

- $\mathbf{Z}[i]/p\mathbf{Z}[i] \cong (\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})[i]$ is not a field, because it has too many fourth roots of unity
- $i-m \not\in p\mathbf{Z}[i]$
- $p | (m-i)(m+i)$ but neither $p | (m-i)$ nor $p | (m+i)$

The ring $\mathbf{Z}[i]$ is a Euclidean domain, which implies it is a unique factorization domain.

Since the prime factorization of $p$ cannot simply be $p$ (nor can it be $(-1) \cdot (-p)$) and cannot be any other product of integers, $p$ must have a prime factor of the form $a+bi$. By conjugation (which is an automorphism of $\mathbf{Z}[i]$ that is the identity on $\mathbf{Z}$), $a-bi$ is also a prime factor of $p$.

Thus $(a+bi)(a-bi) = a^2 + b^2$ is a divisor of $p$. Since it's an integer bigger than $1$, we must actually have $a^2 + b^2 = p$.

Comment: what is an ideal or a prime ideal?

Comment: @J.A: Ah! I'm not sure how to talk about ring theory without knowing about ideals! Maybe think in terms of modular arithmetic then; if $p$ were prime, then when doing modular arithmetic modulo $p$, you could invert any nonzero number (e.g. in this case we could use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find the inverse). However, $(m-i)(m+i) = m^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \bmod p$, but $m-i \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$ and $m+i \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$, because the only Gaussian integers divisible by $p$ are of the form $pa + pbi$. Therefore we have a contradiction, and so $p$ is not prime.

Comment: @J.A: But I guess what I should have said is that saying "$x$ is a prime element of $R$" effectively means the same thing as saying "the set $\{ xr | r \in R \}$ is a prime ideal of $R$". In a "principal ideal domain" (of which $\mathbf{Z}[i]$ is an example), every ideal is of the form $\{xr | r \in R\}$. But there is a more general definition, and in general rings the notion of prime ideal is better behaved than the notion of prime element. e.g. here my argument quickly shows that $\{ ap + b(i-m) | a,b \in \mathbf{Z}[i]\}$ is a prime ideal, but it takes more effort to show that it's principal

Comment: interesting but can you also show $\{ap+b(i-m)|a,b\in\mathbb Z[i]\}$ is principal for completeness?

Comment: @J.A: Yes: it's generated by $\gcd(p, i-b)$. It's the same idea as the fact, in the integers, that every number of the set $\{ am + bn | a,b \in \mathbf{Z}\}$ is a multiple of $\gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: I do not see it. Can you write a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

If $p=4k+1$ then p is sum of two square so we can write $p=a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi)$.
For more information look here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares

Comment: "Assume you do not know $p=a^2+b^2$." Second sentence of the question.

Answer (score 0):

We assume that basic facts about the Gaussian integers being a UFD have been proved. As you pointed out, from the fact that $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ we can conclude that $p$ is not a Gaussian prime.

So some Gaussian prime $a+bi$ is a proper divisor of $p$. The **norm** of $a+bi$ is therefore a proper divisor of $p^2$. It follows that $a+bi$ has norm $p$, meaning that $a^2+b^2=p$.

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by Will Jagy's comment.

We know that $(2k)!^2\equiv(4k)!\equiv(p-1)!\equiv-1\mod p$ and so $x^2+1\equiv 0 \mod p$ has a solution for $x$. Hence $p|(x^2+1)\implies \frac{(x+i)(x-i)}{p}\in\mathbb Z\implies p=(a+bi)(c+di)$.

We know that $a-bi=t(c+di)$ where $t\in \mathbb R$.

We know that $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=p$ as $p^2=p\cdot \bar{p} = (a+bi)(a-bi)(c+di)(c-di)=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)\implies p=a^2+b^2$ and $c^2+d^2.$

$\mbox{So }a-bi=t(c+di)\implies (a-bi)(a+bi)=t(c+di)t(c-di)\implies(a^2+b^2)=t^2(c^2+d^2)\implies pt^2=p\implies t^2=1\implies t=\pm 1\implies p=\pm(a+bi)(a-bi).$

Hence $p=a^2+b^2$ since $p>0$.